# SSD suddenly way slower

Tags: boot, ssd

I have a problem with my SSD, it suddenly got a lot slower. In the task manager it says that it's 50% used all the time. My boot time has doubled and I can't play anything in the first 5 minutes. I use an SSD(240GB) for the OS and have a steam library (HDD 1TB) next to it. I don't get it at all because it won't help to defragmentize and I don't have any more background-programs. The running programs just take up more performance. The drive is about 50% full and my tests are pretty good so it isn't broken.

[image: test]

Comment: How full is the drive?  Have you run any SMART tests?

Comment: If it is used 50% all the time some application is using it. May be your PC is infected with a trojan that encrypts all your data?

Comment: what OS? 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: 64-bit windows and I've only been playing games when it happened, it spiked from 10 to 50%

Comment: what version windows?

Comment: windows 10 1909